# What is the Name of this Process Analysis Software / What Type of Software is it?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, reverse-engineering, analysis, instructions

As the title describes, does anyone know any information on this specific piece of software? I would like to find the literal software in the image. But could suffice with type of software for the purpose of process analysis.

[image: Unknown Process Analysis Software]

I have Google'd for images per generalized descriptions hoping for hits, but have found nothing similar. In addition, the image doesn't give any clues/hints to the software title.

Comment: That's a **debugger** operating in disassembly mode.  (Or it might be one intended for reverse-engineering which doesn't have a source-view mode.  Most debuggers *can* operate that way even if it's not the default.)  Actually, I'm curious what the right-most column comes from; it doesn't quite look like source code.  Oh, I think it's annotating the instructions that set up function args for the GDI function call.

Comment: Why is this tagged [multithreading]?  Are you specifically looking for a debugger that's good at single-stepping multi-threaded processes, like perhaps showing different thread contexts at once when you have them all paused?

Comment: Where did you find that image?

Comment: Try a reverse image search for the program icon

Comment: @Bergi SEE: https://osandamalith.com/2018/04/07/haxing-minesweeper/

Comment: @PeterCordes Noted, thanks. Just figured the tag was relevant in general regards. I want that software specifically; but could suffice with any software that allows me to watch the instructions, without requiring gdb like intrusion.

Comment: *without requiring gdb like intrusion.* - huh?  What do you think this debugger is doing differently from how GDB would behave when attaching to an already-running process?  From the icons at the top bar of the debugger, the existence of a `|>` play button makes me think the process is stopped (as if) at a breakpoint, just like GDB would do when attaching.  In GDB in a text terminal, you can do `layout asm` to see disassembly in its TUI mode, highlighting the current instruction.  (And `layout next` to get asm + registers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Excuse my immaturity. I was thinking GDB breakpoints were not passive, but requiring specific code insertion for control. I have a lot to learn but appreciate all input for experience.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah in a program that reads its own machine code (e.g. to checksum it), it might notice the `0xCC` byte of a software breakpoint as the first byte of an instruction.  But x86 supports hardware breakpoints (via the debug registers) and GDB can use them: use `hbreak` instead of just `break`.  On x86, single-stepping is also hardware-supported fully non-intrusively via the trap flag, TF.  These factors are the same for any debugger; I don't know which debugger this is, but I'd assume it's pretty much the same as GDB.

Comment: Programs being debugged could notice that they're being single-step debugged if they did `pushf` / `pop rax` and checked that bit.  There are some anti-debug tricks that obfuscated programs can use to make debugging hard, or to try to exit if running under a debugger.  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ probably has some Q&As about working around such tricks.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are very knowledge and I love ALL the information. I am seeing how GDB isn't far from OllyDbg, just minus the GUI. I will be exploring quite a few of the things you have mentioned / challenged me with. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 2):

The specific software turns out to be [OllyDbg](https://www.ollydbg.de/) and emphasizes upon Binary Code Analysis; "particularly useful in cases where source is unavailable". Thanks Bergi for the suggestion, this ultimately led me to the software.